# How did this site add that 2px margin between the th elements?

Tags: html, css, space, html-table

I've been looking at the code and I still can't figure out how they achieved the 2px margin between the `th` elements:

[image]

This is the site: http://ecigarettereviewed.com/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}
```

This is actually a browser default style:

[image]

Comment: Strange, I tried to emulate that but in my site there are no margins.

Comment: I just tested it, it works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/eZFzm/ It is the default style in Chrome. If it's not working on your site/project, some other CSS is overriding the style.

Comment: Lol, I saw the downvote, voted you up and now it's down again.

Comment: @alexchenco Strange indeed!

Comment: Strange, maybe my CSS reset is resetting those default styles. SO I added them in my stylesheet and now they work. Thanks.

Comment: Ha I think someone voted you down, I voted you up, and now someone else voted you down again.

Comment: @alexchenco - it's pretty common for most CSS resets to set `border-collapse: collapse` for all tables, so that's probably the issue you're running into.

Comment: @Danny - pretty funny - someone is definitely offended by your answer. I just upvoted it to offset that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the CSS that causes those borders:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 2px;
    -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Where did you pull that code from? `-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 2px;` isn't in the stylesheet: http://ecigarettereviewed.com/wp-content/themes/ecigarettereviewed/style.css

Comment: @Danny - if you click the litte right-arrow in between `border-spacing:>2px`, it'll expand to show you the `-webkit-border-horizontal|vertical-spacing`. It looks like those are the default settings for webkit.