# How did this site add that 2px margin on an element with display:table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tablecell

Following another post with a similar issue: [2px margin between the th elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562679/how-did-this-site-add-that-2px-margin-between-the-th-elements) , I also have this problem but still couldn't fix it with the code written there, cause it's a little different. I have several divs with bootstrap on them. I wanted to center the text vertically and horizontally, so I added the following CSS, any ideas? thanks.

CSS:

```
.tabs_titles {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 4em;
    padding: 10px;
}

.catalog,
.latest_collections,
.contact_tab,
.section_slider {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    padding: 0 30px;
    min-height:450px; 
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="clearfix">

  <div class="catalog col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="tabs_titles"></h2>
  </div> <!-- end catalog -->
  <div class="other_services col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="contact_tab col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <h2 class="tabs_titles"></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="latest_collections col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <h2 class="tabs_titles">צפו בקולקציות הכי חמות שלנו</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="section_slider">
          <h2 class="tabs_titles"></h2>
      </div>
  </div> <!-- end other_services -->

  </section>
```

Comment: Can you provide a functional example?

Comment: what browser are you using? Using the sample posted above, I can not reproduce the "2px margin". Also, are you sure that it does not arise because of the additional classes the definition of which is not included in your post?

Comment: First of all, that site is using tables and you are not. Second, why don't you provide a fiddle or a link to the website. We can't see what is exactly your problem from only the code in your quetion.

Comment: the website is available in this link: (http://toms-projects.com/w-jeans/index.html) . I'm currently working on Chrome. The 2px margin is colored Yellow, on the left side of the screen. Thanks for your help